# iOS mobile devices stretching background image

Tags: ios, css, image, mobile, background

I'm having an issue with my background stressing on iOS devices. It is stretching only when I have added content to a page [like this.](http://www.dontcursekids.com/tunes/) It loads correctly on empty pages [like this](http://www.dontcursekids.com/). I read it has something to do with the adding `background-attachment:scroll` instead of `background-size: cover`. When adding it to the css, I don't get any changes. I must be using the wrong content id. Before I make a more images for a mobile theme, I'm wondering is it anyway I can fix it with code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where would I put this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parallax effect was based on the notion that background images would remain in place with a fixed position while stretching to fit its container. Unfortunately CSS alone won’t let it happen.

Once you set an element to fixed positioning it is essentially removed from the DOM and relative to the window

```
section 
{   
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: -72px;
    background-image: url(http://bgImage);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to change section to #primary to get it to change. I fixed an issue it created the post being above the header by taking out the code for the top and bottom padding. The background looks great now. Thank you again. Only issue is that the content on the page is cut off. I also can't scroll because it cut the player and the social icons on the page off. Is it something I need to add to the position to fix it?

Comment: Okay Great!!. @BryanHoward you can try whit this position: absolute; top:0; left: 0; may be it's help you!!

Comment: The absolute helped. It shows the content more, the background is still correct, and I can scroll now. However it still cuts off at about 80% of the screen from the top. Do I need to change the padding at the bottom too?

Comment: Yes you can do to change the padding at the bottom. I don't  understand what happen with you and without "bottom" pass also check it (Remove Bottom in section and you'll also check).

Comment: Ok let me clarify. The background is fine. While making the position of the background fixed, some how the content on the page is cut off. It doesn't show anything past about 80% of the screen. With absolute it shows more of the content but its cutting off most of it. Including the social icons in the footer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its not the padding, but the actual height of the page thats  cut off. i can't even see my footer.  The code you gave me fixed the background problem however. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code inside your html head tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the late response. i just tried adding this to the head tags in my html, but unfortunately didn't see any changes.

Comment: Np, glad you found an answer anyway!